# Specific JSON format in PHP

Tags: php, json

i need this json format with php code

is there any way to generate JSON like this
with PHP ?

```
[
      {
         "name":"Steve",
         "company":"Apple"
      },
      {
         "name":"Bill",
         "company":"Microsoft"
      }
]
```

can anyone help ?

Comment: `json_encode()` should do it.  Or do you mean you want it with the exact indentations?

Comment: yes, i need exactly like this , with recurrence

Comment: What version of PHP is your server running? `json_encode` was not bundled as part of the PHP standard library until 5.2.0.If you are running 5.2.0 or later, then `json_encode` is definitely the way to go.

Comment: You could get a pretty close result with the **JSON_PRETTY_PRINT** option, but you'll need PHP >= 5.4.0.  See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).  Otherwise, you'll have to do your own maths.

Comment: What is your starting data? A PHP array like `array(array("name"=>"Steve", …), …)`, or a JSON string without the indentation, like `'[{"name":Steve",…},…]'`?

Comment: @ Rory, my json will be, [{"name":Steve",…},…] array without indentation

Comment: thanks to everyone who shared their views here.

Comment: @SunilLohar http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26688/maharashtrian-code-worriars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to do this:

```
$a = array();
$b = array('name' => '', 'company' => '');

$b['name'] = 'Steve';
$b['company'] = 'Apple';
$a[]= $b;

$b['name'] ='Bill';
$b['company']='Microsoft';
$a[]= $b;

echo json_encode($a);
```

This will give you

```
[
  {
    "name": "Steve",
    "company": "Apple"
  },
  {
    "name": "Bill",
    "company": "Microsoft"
  }
]
```

Comment: thanks Arfeen, this worked with loop.

Answer (score 2):

use `json_encode`

```
$var = json_encode($array);
```

Comment: how to get that JSON with recurrence , i mean name (key) will come again and again with its value.

Comment: what is your input?? show in question.

Comment: there will be n number of entries in my program, say thousand names and thousand company names, so how can i manage JSON with above format ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `json_encode` like this:

```
$my_data = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Steve',
        'company' => 'Apple'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Bill',
        'company' => 'Microsoft'
    )
);
echo json_encode($my_data);
```

It does not matter that both of the inner arrays contain the same keys because they are still in *separate arrays* and will form properly when encoded in JSON.

Comment: in my program, number of entries will not be fixed, how to do it programatically ?

Comment: You'll just need a `for`/`foreach` loop to iterate over all of the entries.

Comment: the first level of arrays all revert to numeric indeces thus doing a print_r would result into array(
   0=> array(
        'name' => 'Steve',
        'company' => 'Apple'
    ),
   1=> array(
        'name' => 'Bill',
        'company' => 'Microsoft'
    )

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
json_encode($variableName);
```

Answer (score 1):

This

```
$array = array (
  array ('name' => 'Steve', 'company' => 'Apple', ),
  array ('name' => 'Bill', 'company' => 'Microsoft', ),
);
$result = json_encode($array);
```

And this

```
$person_steve = new stdClass;
$person_steve->name = 'Steve';
$person_steve->company = 'Apple';
$person_bill = new stdClass;
$person_bill->name = 'Bill';
$person_bill->company = 'Microsoft';
$array = array ($person_steve, $person_bill);
$result = json_encode($array);
```

Comment: but there will be n number of entries in my program, how can i manage those ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
# To Output
die(json_encode($myarray));

# To Store
$myJson = json_encode($myarray);
```

Comment: how to get that JSON with recurrence , i mean name (key) will come again and again with its value.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note on json_encode you will need to add the square brackets if your code requires it.

```
echo '['.json_encode(array('index1'=>1)).']';
```

Comment: but how to get that JSON with recurrence , i mean name (key) will come again and again with its value.